# Reading Active Directory User Names in jsp

Tags: java, active-directory

I tried to read the User Names which are in the Active Directory, but I am getting an error. The error is:
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903AA, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, v1772]

However, my code is:

```
package client;
    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.InitialContext;
    import javax.naming.directory.*;
    import javax.naming.ldap.*;
    import javax.naming.*;
    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import java.util.Enumeration;
public class AD {
    public AD() {
        super();
    }


            public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
                    Hashtable envVars = new Hashtable();
                    envVars.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
                    envVars.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + "IP:Port");
                    envVars.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
                    envVars.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
                    envVars.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");


                    DirContext myContext = new InitialDirContext(envVars);
                    try{

                    SearchControls searchCtrls = new SearchControls();
                    searchCtrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
                    String[] attributes = { "cn", "telephoneNumber", "sn", "userPrincipalName","memberOf","name" };
                    searchCtrls.setReturningAttributes(attributes);


                    String filter = "(objectClass=organizationalPerson)";
                    NamingEnumeration values = myContext.search("CN=Users,DC=bma.gov.bh,DC=gov,DC=bh",filter, searchCtrls);
                    while (values.hasMoreElements())
                    {
                           SearchResult result = (SearchResult) values.next();
                            Attributes attribs = result.getAttributes();


                            if (null != attribs)
                            {
                                    for (NamingEnumeration ae = attribs.getAll(); ae.hasMoreElements();)
                                    {
                                            Attribute atr = (Attribute) ae.next();
                                            String attributeID = atr.getID();
                                            for (
                                                    Enumeration vals = atr.getAll(); 
                                                    vals.hasMoreElements(); 
                                                    System.out.println(attributeID +": " +vals.nextElement()) );
                                    }
                            }
                    }


                    myContext.close();


                    }

                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                            //e
                    }
            }



}
```

The problem is starting from this line:

```
DirContext myContext = new InitialDirContext(envVars);
```

Can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code you got `80090308` can be found in [winerror.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819775.aspx) - and it says

> The token supplied to the function is invalid

Most probably this is caused by the fact that Active Directory expects the password to be UTF-8 encoded byte array, and the Java string is not that.

Try changing your code as this:

```
envVars.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password".getBytes("UTF8"));
```

Comment: I tried to replace the above line and it gave me an error on .getBytes

Comment: Exceptions is not handled : java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException

Comment: Just surround it with try-catch clause for this exception, UTF8 is always supported, so you can safely ignore it. `try { envVars.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password".getBytes("UTF8")); } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) { /* ignore */ }`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But, it is showing an error that the connection failed.

Answer (score 1):

Be carreful, this problem is not completely identified by the code 80090308. Because the data code give some details about the problem:

- 525  user not found
- 52e  invalid credentials
- 530  not permitted to logon at this time
- 531  not permitted to logon at this workstation
- 532  password expired
- 533  account disabled
- 701  account expired
- 773  user must reset password
- 775  user account locked

See this page for more detail: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21290631

Many thanks to IBM Support!